# Selenium Timout on RaspberryPi at Expected Condition

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, raspberry-pi

#### Task

I want to perform a web task using Selenium, geckodriver (ARM build) and Iceweasel on my RaspberryPi 3. The code runs seamlessly on my development machine (Ubuntu, Intel, 64bit), of course using the suitable geckodriver build. The code also prooved successful inside a dockerized container. However, when executing on the RaspberryPi, I get the stated timeout error.

#### Code

The website is opened in a new window, hence I am switching to the second in `window.handles`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from helpers.automation_helper import *

to_website.click()

el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)
)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

while get_events_left(driver):
    ...
```

In the opened page, I expect edit buttons (= my events) which I intend to return as soon as they are visible. An empty array shall be returned if no events are available, so causing the while loop not to be executed. The expected condition is where the error occurs on the RaspberryPi.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def get_events_left(driver):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@id, 'protocolEvent')]"))
    )
    return driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[./span/span/svg-icon[@name='edit']]")
```

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 61, in <module>
    while get_events_left(driver):
  File "/path/to/app/helpers/automation_helper.py", line 39, in get_events_left
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'protocolEvent')]"))
  File "/path/to/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Did you try to increase timeout? This could happen because of raspberry hardware performance. Also, you can try to change browser to chrome (more quick).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have just bumped it up to 40 seconds but this does not solve the issue as I expected. Surely, the RaspberryPi is not the fastest but I can not imagine it taking longer than 20 or even 40 seconds. I too thought about switching to Chrome and chromedriver. Sadly, there is no ARM build of chromedriver suitable for the RaspberryPi.

Comment: Maybe these links will help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194176,  https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7341wt/success_how_to_run_selenium_chrome_webdriver_on/